# I have Problems specifying my model to solve with LP-Solver on javascript

Tags: javascript, linear-programming, linear-optimization

```js
var obj_1 = 
{
    "name": "Strompreis",
    "optimize": "kosten",
    "opType": "min",
    "constraints": {

        "E_L_1": {
            "max":e_bn*0.5,
        },
        "E_L_2": {
            "max":e_bn*0.5,
        },
        "E_L_3": {
            "max":e_bn*0.5,
        },
       

        "E_E_1": {
            "max":e_bn,
        },
        "E_E_2": {
            "max":e_bn,
        },
        "E_E_3": {
            "max":e_bn,
        },

        
        "E_Netz_1": {
            "max":e_netz_max,
            "min": 0,
        },
        "E_Netz_2": {
            "max":e_netz_max,
            "min": 0,
        },
        "E_Netz_3": {
            "max":e_netz_max,
            "min": 0,
        },


        "E_PV_1": {
            "equal": e_pv[10],
        },
        "E_PV_2": {
            "equal": e_pv[11],
        },
        "E_PV_3": {
            "equal":  e_pv[12],
        },
        
        "E_V_1": {
            "equal": e_v[10],
        },
        "E_V_2": {
            "equal": e_v[11],
        },
        "E_V_3": {
            "equal": e_v[12],
        },
           
        "soc_1": {"min": soc_min,"max":soc_max, "equal":soc_start},
        "soc_2": {"min": soc_min,"max":soc_max},
        "soc_3": {"min": soc_min,"max":soc_max},

           
    },
    "variables": {
        "E_Netz_1": {
            "kosten": parseFloat((preis[0]).toFixed(2)),  
        },
        "E_Netz_2": {
            "kosten": parseFloat((preis[1]).toFixed(2)),
        },
        "E_Netz_3": {
            "kosten": parseFloat((preis[2]).toFixed(2)),
        },

        "soc_1": {"soc_2":1},
        "soc_2": {"soc_3":1},
        "soc_3": {"kosten":30*e_bn}, //30cent für soc am Ende

        "E_E_1": {"soc_2":-1/e_bn,"E_Netz_1":-1},
        "E_E_2": {"soc_3":-1/e_bn,"E_Netz_2":-1},
        "E_E_3": {"E_Netz_3":-1},
        
        "E_L_1": {"soc_2":1/e_bn,"E_Netz_1":1},
        "E_L_2": {"soc_3":1/e_bn,"E_Netz_2":1},
        "E_L_3": {"E_Netz_3":1},


        "E_PV_1":{"E_Netz_1":-1},
        "E_PV_2":{"E_Netz_2":-1},
        "E_PV_3":{"E_Netz_3":-1},

        "E_V_1":{"E_Netz_1":1},
        "E_V_2":{"E_Netz_2":1},
        "E_V_3":{"E_Netz_3":1},


    }
};
```

This should be my model to solve. But every time I try to solve it, I get that the problem is unfeasible.

```
Solution {feasible: false, evaluation: 0, bounded: true, _tableau: Tableau, solutionSet: {…}}
```

How can I check if the model is okay?

I'm expecting the program to return the values of the variables like `E_E_X` and `E_L_X`, which are not defined at the beginning. ("with this variables is this minimum reachable")